# How to measure the distance between two objects in different planes in a video

Tags: python, video, augmented-reality, distance

I am trying to measure the distance between two objects in a video (Euclidean distance) using Python and openCV etc. I am trying to figure out a solution on how to implement this algorithm and so far my code can find two objects. As shown below, I need to find the distance between an acetylene cylinder and an oxygen cylinder, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I checked the internet, but most of them require the camera to be level and most of them can only measure distances to the same depth.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the angle of the camera? Do you know the objects' distance from the camera? The focal length of the camera? I'm not familiar with how to deal with perspective distortion, but if you know the focal length, you could probably measure the angle between the two objects and the camera. You could construct a triangle using the angle and the distances between the objects and the camera, then solve for the length of the missing side.

Comment: following up what @ArnoldPalmer said, you could be able to find this information (or some of it) in the **exif tags** of the video.

Comment: augmented reality task. I've tagged it such.